# need to mock POST request in cypress

Tags: testing, cypress, e2e-testing

UPDATED 9/16:
I've reworded my question. I'm trying to use cypress to test a work application that has an Angular frontend(http://localhost:4200) and a .NET Core backend (http://localhost:5000).

When the app starts, a login page loads with username and password fields. The cypress code test fills in the username and password and clicks the submit button, as show in my code below.

When the login (submit) button is clicked, it triggers a POST request to the .NET Core backend. The request submits the username and password and if the user is verified, a token comes back in response. The token is added to session storage and the user is logged in. It is this token value in the session storage that signifies the user is logged in. With the token added, the user gets redirected to the homepage.

Now the backend is NOT running. I need to simulate this POST request so the cypress test can get to the actual homepage.

I think I need to stub this POST request but I can't get this code to work. The request just aborts and looking at the console it says the request was not stubbed.

Here's my updated cypress code:

```
  const username = 'johndoe';
  const password = 'pass1234';
  
  cy.server();
  cy.get('h1').should('contain', 'Login');
  cy.get('input[placeholder=Username]').type(username);
  cy.get('input[placeholder=Password]').type(password);
  cy.get('button[type=submit]').click();  
  cy.route({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/Authentication/Login',
    response: {
      access_token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9' // some random characters
    }
  });
```

Comment: What is the intention of your `cy.request()`? Note that [cy.route() cannot be debugged using cy.request()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#cy-route-cannot-be-debugged-using)

Comment: I'm trying to simulate a login.

Comment: Doubtful if that code logs in - how does the app know it's logged in if you are stubbing the server and also triggering the login request from the test? Surely you need to hit the app's login button, or equivalent.

Comment: Removed my answer. Based on eric99's link, it won't work.

Comment: @Ackroydd I reworded my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update for cy.intercept()

The syntax is nearly the same, except now `cy.route()` is `cy.intercept()`, and `cy.server()` is no longer needed.

The problem in the question is still solved by the same pattern: the `cy.intercept()` should be set up ***before*** the application triggers the request.

```js
cy.intercept('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/Authentication/Login', {
  // static response object here
})
...
cy.get('button[type=submit]').click();
```

---

You might have more success if you set up the route before invoking the POST (clicking submit),

```js
cy.server();
cy.route({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/Authentication/Login',
  response: {
    access_token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9' // some random characters
  }
});
...
cy.get('button[type=submit]').click();
```

However, if your app uses [native fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) as opposed to XHR, core Cypress does not catch this type of request. You have to add a [polyfill](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/29/experimental-fetch-polyfill) which essentially modifies the `window.fetch` method to allow `cy.route()` to succeed.

**cypress.json**

```
{  
  "experimentalFetchPolyfill": true
}
```

Please note the limitations section,

> **Limitations**
> The experimental polyfill is not foolproof.  It does not work with fetch calls made from WebWorkers or ServiceWorker for example. It might not work for streaming responses and canceled XHRs. That's why we felt the opt-in experimental flag is the best path forward to avoid breaking already application under tests.

Comment: cy.server has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Cypress has been updated, since version 12.0.0 you can use `cy.intercept` to mock any response

- cypress documentation on [network requests](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests)
- cypress doc on the [cy.intercept](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept)

```js
cy.intercept(
  {
    method: "GET", // or another method e.g. "POST
    url: `<MOCKED_API_URL>`, // change to your desired API endpoint
  },
  MOCKED_RESPONSE,
).as("mocked"); // or any other name, just will be used for the cy.wait later

cy.visit("url-you-want-to-visit");
cy.wait("@mocked");

// ... continue your testing
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stubbing the API inside cypress you can instead use a
[dedicated](https://apidog.com/blog/best-api-mock-tools/)
[API](https://katalon.com/resources-center/blog/what-is-api-mocking)
[mock](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/api-mocking)
[solution](https://speedscale.com/blog/api-mocking-tools/),
for instance [Mocks Server](https://www.mocks-server.org/) (notice plural s - *mocks*, not to be confused with a similar project called [MockServer](https://www.mock-server.com/)...).

The following is what is needed to simulate your use case:

```bash
mkdir so-question
cd so-question
npm init -y
npm install --save-dev @mocks-server/main
sed -i '/"scripts"/a\    "mocks": "mocks-server",' package.json
mkdir -p mocks/routes
touch .mocksrc.yaml mocks/collections.yaml mocks/routes/login.yaml
code . # Edit files as below
npm run mocks
```

`.mocksrc.yaml`:

```yaml
server:
  port: 5000
mock:
  collections:
    selected: "base"
```

`mocks/collections.yaml`:

```yaml
- id: "base"
  routes:
    - "login:success"
```

`mocks/routes/login.yaml`:

```yaml
- id: "login"
  url: "/Authentication/Login"
  method: "POST"
  variants:
    - id: "success"
      type: "json"
      options:
        status: 200
        body:
          access_token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"
```

With that you will get:

```
$ curl -d '' http://localhost:5000/Authentication/Login
{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"}
$
```

For the [cypress integration](https://www.mocks-server.org/docs/integrations/cypress/) part there is [this blog post](https://www.javierbrea.com/blog/cypress-mock-server/) that goes into details but summary for your case would be to replace `cy.server` and `cy.route` with `cy.mocksSetCollection("base")`, called some time before the `click` (possibly in a `before` as described in the blog post).